# Tomcat: Program is not running from webapps

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I am trying to run a jsp program with Tomcat.If I am keeping my project in webapps folder with the WEB-INF file, it is not getting run. Instead it is running from webapps/ROOT folder. I want it to run from webapps. please guide me.

Comment: you have other option 1) build your project war file 2) Run your tomcat using command prompt 3) deploy your war in tomcat

Answer (score 0):

The way tomcat works and is preconfigured is to pick up the directory name of a directory in `webapps` and use this as the name of the application you're running - with the notable exception of ROOT. ROOT is a special name, indicating that this is handled without a context name, directly at the root of your server (as you couldn't have empty directory names).

If you have `webapps/ROOT` and `webapps/myApp`, your server would have one webapp answering on `http://example.com/` and `http://example.com/myApp`. This is just the way tomcat comes. While you *can* configure it to work differently I'd think the only value repurposing the webapps folder for this purpose will only serve to confuse others that will maintain your application later.

Rather enjoy the fact that you get an amazing piece of infrastructure with tomcat, accept the defaults that it provides you, bite the bullet and deploy your application in the proper place, namely webapps/ROOT or webapps/myApp.